# Center content over full screen slick slider

Tags: html, css, center, slick.js

I'm trying to center content over a fullscreen slick slider ([kenwheeler.github.io/slick/](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)),

I've attempted to use a flex box but the content remains at the edge of the viewport, which appears to be an issue with the `position` tag of the *slick* css but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

It's my first time working with flex so maybe I'm missing something?

[Website live here](http://hotlovegym.com/test/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="main">
  <img class="logo" src="img/logo.png">
  <h1><a href="#">XXXXXX</a></h1>
  <h2>XXXX is a collaboration between <a href="#">XXXX</a> & <a href="#">XXXX</a></h2>
</div>
<div class="background">
  <div class="slide" style="background: url('bg/hlg1.jpg') no-repeat center center"></div>
  <div class="slide" style="background: url('bg/hlg2.jpg') no-repeat center center"></div>
  <div class="slide" style="background: url('bg/hlg3.jpg') no-repeat center center"></div>
  <div class="slide" style="background: url('bg/hlg4.jpg') no-repeat center center"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
*{
  min-height: 0;
  min-width: 0;
  cursor: crosshair;
}

html{
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body{
  font-family: sans-serif, "Helvetica", "Arial";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 62.5%;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.slide {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover !important;
}

.background {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
}

.slick-list,
.slick-track {
  height: 100%;
}

.slick-prev {
  position: fixed;
  left: 2vw;
  height: 4vh;
  width: 3vw;
  z-index: 2;
}

.slick-next {
  position: fixed;
  right: 2vw;
  height: 4vh;
  width: 3vw;
  z-index: 2;
}

.slick-slider {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.arrow:hover {
  cursor: crosshair;
}

.main {
  flex: none;
  top: 3vh;
  z-index: 1;
  max-width: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}

.logo {
  width: 25vw;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since that element (main) stays there all the time, you can use these settings:

```
.main {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    z-index: 1;
}
```